# Install gawk-csv (or gawkextlib) with apt

Tags: apt, awk, gnu

There are a way to install the [CSV extension for `gawk`](http://gawkextlib.sourceforge.net/csv/gawk-csv.html#Installing-the-CSV-extension)  by `apt`?

---

The name of the main lib is `gawkextlib`.

It is a very important extension for [classic AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK), because generic CSV file is not only "`a,b,c`", AWK need to parse [standard CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) quotations, escaped lines, etc.

PS: the [installation from source-code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/574956/130402) is ugly and not works for UBUNTU 18 LTS.

Comment: Is there really a period at the end of your command (`... && make install.`)? if so, remove it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been cross-posted and already received attention [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574956/how-to-install-gawk-csv-and-gawkextlib)

Comment: Hi @steeldriver, I edited to preserve scope: looking for `apt` or similar installation process.

Comment: OK close vote retracted

Comment: This might be a good alternative: https://github.com/dbro/csvquote/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -p /opt/gawk && cd /opt/gawk
apt-get source gawk
apt-get build-dep gawk
cd "gawk-4.1.3+dfsg"
dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -us -uc
cd /opt && git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/gawkextlib/code gawkextlib-code
cd gawkextlib-code
./build.sh lib $(grep -Po '(?<=\$\ ./configure\ ).*' /opt/gawk/gawk-4.1.3+dfsg/config.log)
./build.sh csv $(grep -Po '(?<=\$\ ./configure\ ).*' /opt/gawk/gawk-4.1.3+dfsg/config.log)
```

Comment: The `apt-get` generated other version and must use quotes, `cd "gawk-4.1.3+dfsg"`... How to specify version 5 for apt?  Need before to `purge` all files of v4?

Comment: there are only the ./configure options (that long line in the beginning) from config.log that are of interest after that you can delete the gawk source. ```./build.sh lib --build=x86_64-linux-gnu ...```

Comment: Hi @bac0n but about first and main question, how to apt install v5?

Comment: Well about v4, after `dpkg-buildpackage -b -rfakeroot -us -uc` fineched with `... dpkg-buildpackage: binary-only upload (no source included)`. Git of but after first `./build.sh lib $(...)` error *"grep: /opt/gawk/gawk-5.0.1+dfsg/config.log: No such file or directory"*. I changed to `gawk-4.1.3+dfsg`  but same error.

Comment: you can get the options from config.log (its that first long line) in gawk source manually and paste it to ./build lib|csv --alot --of --options --from --gawk